# How do I save selected dates to database from jQuery calendar

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, calendar

My goal here is to store a list of dates selected in a calandar to a database. The problem with most calendar controls that exist, for asp.net, is I can't get the date that was unselected with multiselect enabled. I can get a list but that is really it. I have decided not to use these because of this.

If I wanted to create my own event using the jQuery calendar below how would I go about doing this? The event would capture the day clicked, if it was unselected or selected, etc. I would use this to add/remove the dates from a collection. It is almost like how the other calendars work except for the remove part. The dates removed would be in it's own list so I know what dates to remove from the database once 'save' is clicked. I hope this is enough information.

http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/#about

Using Visual Studio 2005/.NET 2.0. c#

Comment: I would still like to know if anyone has any answers to my question. But, what I ended up doing was just using one of the controls and, in JS, assigning the last clicked date to a hidden field. Then I used the hidden field as the last clicked date. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to save multiple dates (list), you could:
-use jquery to create 1 input box for selecting date and another list area the selected dates
-on post back, have the server code check the list area for all the selected dates

if you wanted to save only one date, you could:
-use jquery to create 1 input box for selecting date
-on post back, the server code check for the that input box

hope that helps.